# (Product) Lebesgue measure on infinite dimensional spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, measure-theory

I am trying to understand measure construction procedures on infinite-dimensional spaces. Why is it not possible in general to construct Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_is_no_infinite-dimensional_Lebesgue_measure#Proof_of_the_theorem

Comment: Thanks. This is a very nice link!

Comment: @Samuel: Note that the proof in the link needs modification, since it is written for Banach spaces, but the idea is the same: any open set contains infinitely many translates of a smaller open set.

Comment: @NateEldredge How would you modify this proof if we drop the Banach assumption?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will prove it for $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$. (A proof for all Banach spaces is given [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_is_no_infinite-dimensional_Lebesgue_measure#Proof_of_the_theorem).)

Consider the cube $(-1,1]^{\mathbb N}$. It can be partitioned into infinitely many translated copies of the cube $(0,1]^{\mathbb N}$, so if we want them all to have the same volume, and the cube $(-1,1]^{\mathbb N}$ to have finite volume, then the volume of each must be $0$. Now, we can cover the entire space $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ with countably many copies of the cube $(0,1]^{\mathbb N}$, so the entire space $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ must have measure $0$, and thus all subsets must also have measure $0$. Thus the only finite translation-invariant complete measure on $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ is the trivial measure $0$.

Comment: The first step seems incorrect to me. You require uncountably many copies of the cube of side-length 1 to partition the cube of side-length 2 (right?).

Comment: It is also incorrect to say that $\mathbb R^\mathbb N$ is covered by countably many $(0,1]^\mathbb N.$

Answer (score 3):

I am not quite sure what you mean. But the construction of Lebesgue measure on $X$ I learnt is by using the Riesz representation theorem to identify Lebesgue measure as one continuous linear functional over $C(X)$. But this requires the $X$ to be locally compact, and if $X$ is a vector space, the only locally compact ones are $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: The following old article of Oxtoby [Oxtoby J.C., Invariant measures in groups which are not locally compact, Trans. AMS., 60 (1946), 215--237] contains general constructions of left-invariant quasi-finite Borel measures on Polish groups that are not locally compact. This article contains answers to all questions stated above.

Answer (score 3):

First constructions of "Lebesgue measure" on $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ can be found in papers:

[1]  Baker R., "Lebesgue measure" on $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$,
Proc. Amer. Math. Soc., vol. 113, no. 4, 1991,
pp.1023--1029.

[2]  Baker R., "Lebesgue measure" on $\mathbb{R}^{ \infty}$.
II. Proc. Amer. Math. Soc., vol. 132, no. 9, 2003, pp. 2577--2591.

Some  generalizations of  Baker  constructions can be found in the following articles:

[3] G. Pantsulaia, On ordinary and Standard Lebesgue Measures on  $\mathbb R^{\infty}$, Bull. Polish Acad. Sci., 73(3) (2009), 209-222.

[4]  G. Pantsulaia, On a standard product of an arbitrary family  of finite Borel  measures with domain in Polish spaces, Theory Stoch. Process, vol. 16(32), 2010, no 1, p.84-93.

[5]  G. Pantsulaia, On ordinary and standard products of infinite family of $\sigma$-finite measures and some of their applications, Acta Math. Sin. (Engl. Ser.), 27 (2011), no. 3, 477--496.

Comment: Thanks for the references!

Answer (score -3):

Feynman has done something like this when he defines path integral. It is infinite dimensional measure.

$\int_{\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}}d^{\infty}x \mathcal{Dx}e^{i\mathcal{S}[x]}$

Is such beautiful formula but many mathematician have problem justifying? Answer: Is not infinite dimensional measure.

Comment: Just wanted to clarify a misconception about this path-integral. The problem is not about defining an infinite dim Lebesgue measure. In fact there are many ways to circumvent this problem, such as the Feynman-Kac formula which uses the Wiener measure. There’s also the method of defining an infinite dim Gaussian measure (Bochner’s theorem) since that usually corresponds to the free Hamiltonian.